# PHP MySQL comparison always true regardless of operands and operator

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp, boolean

For the record, I read documentation on boolean comparisons in PHP, but I do not understand how my code relates in this context. I thought I had a problem connecting to MySQL, but it turns out everything is fine and I can make queries without issue. So, MySQL is not really that relevant to this post.

I use this to report errors in an object that tried to connect on construction. Note that I tried ==, ===, != and !== only to get the same problem. I even tried casting the argument to bool and boolean.

Comments in below code blocks are relevant.

```
private function assert($test){ // Tried renaming in case PHP was funny about it.
    if ($test === FALSE){ // Tried ==, ===, !== and != and casting $test.
        if ($this->use_exception){
            throw new mysql_exception();
        }else{
            die("MySQL ".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
```

Connecting is typical.

```
$this->con = mysql_connect($host, $un, $pw, false, $ssl ? MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL : 0);

// I get 'yay'
echo mysql_ping($this->con) ? "yay" : "nay";

// This disagrees. Tried no cast, and a cast to bool.
$this->assert((boolean)($this->con != FALSE));
```

mysql_ping() says everything is ok, but assert() stops the presses no matter what.

I tried every operator and cast combination, even renaming the function out of paranoia over a name clash. Why does assert() only see true?

**EDIT:**

To make my problem clearer, consider the alternative implementation with Eugen's suggested use of is_resource. The problem is that I just have no idea why the below happens.

```
private function assert($test){
    $test = $test ? true : false;
    if ($test === FALSE){
        echo "$test === false<br />";
    }
    if ($test == FALSE){
        echo "$test == false<br />";
    }
    if ($test !== FALSE){
        echo "$test !== false<br />";
    }
    if ($test == FALSE){
        echo "$test != false<br />";
    }
}
```

Output is out of order and the value changed after one comparison. Since I can make queries, $test must be true. I should not get output at all, but I do for every operator. I also tried it with FALSE replaced by 0.

Bad PHP instance?

```
1 !== false
=== false
!== false
!= false
```

Comment: What are you passing as $test?

Comment: You get `yay` from `mysql_ping` which means `$this->con` is not in fact `FALSE` which means `$this->con != FALSE` should avaluate to `true` just like it does...

Comment: so what's the problem? As I understand from your post, the connection is successful and the function returns a link identifier as it should which will always assert to true .. 
L.E.: the manual says "Returns a MySQL link identifier on success or FALSE on failure." so I guess you should test `if ($this->con === FALSE)`

Comment: @Mchl `$this->con != FALSE` evaluating to `true` should mean `($test === FALSE)`evaluating to `false`, and NOT "stopping the presses", I suspect the OP to mean "Why does assert() only see false"

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->assert(is_resource($this->con));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to contribute! I tried this line, but the result is the same: assert() still kills the script regardless of how I tell it to interpret the argument.

Comment: I added a new example to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

can't you use your second example and combine the function? you already get a value (yay/nay)

```
$this->con = mysql_connect($host, $un, $pw, false, $ssl ? MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL : 0);
$this->assert = mysql_ping($this->con) ? 1 : 0;
```

just thinking out loud

Comment: unless assert is a function that does something .. sorry if i am mistaken and assert is more than a boolean data point.

Comment: Looking at your code, do you mean make $this->assert a property for __set to work with? As for checking the value in $this->connect(), I would prefer to keep error checking in a separate method so just so I do not have to pepper die(), mysql_error() and mysql_errno() throughout the class definition. EDIT: Yes, it is a method.

Comment: with your code are you expecting $this->assert to be a boolean value of 0 or 1? my code should do the trick, then you can add the "if ($assert) { mysqlquery and the like }" ... assert is not a predefined function or method correct? looking at your code above you are defining the assert function to perform similar function as my line of code.